# How to fix a function to get the text color of a cell

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have created a function to get the text color of a cell when I insert the formula in another cell. My aim is to filter rows by color.

Steps:

**1. Create the code:**

```
function getHex(input) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(input).getFontColor();
};
```

**2. Type the function in cell M2, for example:**

```
=getHex("C2:C10")
```

**3. Range M2:M10 will return the font color from C2:C10.**

This function worked with `.getBackgrounds()` (https://www.techjunkie.com/filter-by-color-google-sheets/), but it is not working with `.getFontColor()`. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Hi Bernardo, are you trying to just write the string of the hex color of the cells, (in the M2:M10 range in this example). If you call getFontColor on a range it will only return the color for the top-left cell, you should use getFontColors to get all the colors for the range in an array

Comment: Have you already looked at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range for a method that returns a array of values instead of a single value? Also look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions.

Comment: Hi Alberto! It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Posting this to leave the answer documented.

If you call `getFontColor()` on a range it will only return the color for the top-left cell of the range (this method is what you would normally use for evaluating a single cell), you should use `getFontColors()` which returns all the colors for the range in an array.

As far as I can see in the documentation available at the moment, many of the Range Class methods follow this pattern, there’s a method to get a single value and another to get an array of the same values, same happens with `getBackground()` & `getBackgrounds()`, for example, this has to do with how ranges can be used for both aggregations of cells as well as single ones. Below is a link to the documentation, it should help you with any other doubts.

Documentation URL: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontcolors

Comment: Thank you, Alberto! Got it.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!